# test android application by not developer

Tags: android

What the best way (in terms of efforts) to test android application by ordinary users (that have no ability to install android sdk, connect usb cable and so on things)?

I see two variants:

1. Google Play + alpha/beta versions restricted only for several users, but according to [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) delay may be several hours, and it is too long for me.
   Is it possible to reduce this time delay to several minutes? Is it possible to automate, so our CI upload apk file after each commit?
2. Publish apk file on our web server, so user can install it via download. But I tried this way by myself, and for some reason apk file was openned by program that can open zip files, and this program not suggest install it, I have to install additional file manager, find apk file in download folder and install it with help of file manager. Is it expected behaviour for android, when I open external apk file?

may be there is more variants?

Comment: "Is it expected behaviour for android, when I open external apk file? " -- that depends entirely on how your server is configured. If your server is configured to serve `.apk` files with a MIME type of `application/zip`, then yes. It should be `application/vnd.android.package-archive`. "may be there is more variants?" -- use a file sharing service (e.g., Dropbox).